# Enviar Post com dados de Modelo que os atributos são classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou tentando enviar um Post através de um formulário, mas no controller os atributos que são classes estão chegando como null, como eu deveria fazer para que consiga pegar certinho os dados para que eu possa cadastrar no banco?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult SalvarPedido(Pedido pedido)
{
    this._dataService.NewPedido(pedido);

    return RedirectToAction("CadPedido", "Manager", new { msg = "Registro salvo com sucesso" });
}
```

Modelo ( O Usuario, Veiculo e cliente estão vindo como null )

```
   public class Pedido
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Usuario Funcionario { get; set; }
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public Veiculo Veiculo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataRetirada { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataDevolucaoPrevista { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataDevolucao { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cadastro de Pedido";
}

@model Pedido

<div class="dark-form">
    <h3 class="title-dark-form">Cadastrar novo pedido</h3>
    <form asp-action="SalvarPedido" asp-controller="Manager" method="post">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="Funcionario" class="col-md-2">Funcionario: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select asp-for="Funcionario" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var funcionario in ViewBag.Usuarios)
                    {
                        <option value="@funcionario.Id">@funcionario.NomeCompleto</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="Cliente" class="col-md-2">Cliente: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select asp-for="Cliente" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var cliente in ViewBag.Clientes)
                    {
                        <option value="@cliente.Id">@cliente.NomeCompleto</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="Veiculo" class="col-md-2">Veículo: </label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select asp-for="Veiculo" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var veiculo in ViewBag.Veiculos)
                    {
                        <option value="@veiculo.Id">@veiculo.Modelo</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="DataRetirada" class="col-md-2">Data Retirada: </label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="date" asp-for="DataRetirada" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <label for="DataDevolucaoPrevista" class="col-md-2">Data Devolução: </label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="date" asp-for="DataDevolucaoPrevista" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row form-group">
            <label for="valorPrevisto" class="col-md-2">Valor Previsto: </label>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="valorPrevistro">

            </div>
        </div>
     <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Limpar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Todos estão chegando null? Tentou adicionar o `[FromBody]`, `SalvarPedido([FromBody]Pedido pedido)`

Comment: já tentei, mas fazendo isso para de funcionar, vai para uma página em branco e não entra no controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei o problema, onde estava usando o asp-for para os campos que são modelos, estava colocando apenas o nome do modelo e não o campo, apenas alterei de Cliente , Veiculo e Usuario para Cliente.Id, Veiculo.Id e Usuario.Id

Answer (score 0):

Vc tem que colocar o caminho completo do modelo. 
Exemplo: @model NomeDoProjeto.Models.Pedido

Comment: Já adicionei a pasta Models no Imports, por isso não precisei adicionar o caminho completo, não é esse o problema.